Do local review boards have jurisdiction on the projects of higher authorities?
In my line of work, I've always been told that if a County wants to complete a project on County land, then they can simply perform the work and are not required to get permits from the planning boards of the local governments.
For example, if a Asbury County wants to rehabilitate an historic house located in Beach Township, the County does not have to get approvals for their work from the local Planning Board. They would need to be reviewed by the County Board and possibly an entity on the State level, but they wouldn't be subject to the local review.
Similarly, if the State DOT wanted to complete a road project that required some widening along with the required eminent domain, they would not be subject to being reviewed by the local level.
I'm inquiring about my experience in NJ and am curious if there's some sort of State statute that supports this or if there's some general concept in law that I'm not aware of. In discussion with some of my colleagues, they've all indicated that it's true that the local boards don't have review authority on projects by entities of greater authority (i.e. County, State, Federal), but no one could tell me why.
Also, if there is a specific rule, is there a limit on it? For example, if the State owned a property in the middle of a suburban house development, could they elect to put a 20-story apartment building perhaps in conformance with a governor's order to provide more affordable housing?

The assertion that permits are not needed is not correct. You insist it is.

@Mimedfp you are welcome to offer examples in your answer of instances when a State had to get approval from a local board. At current, the only evidence you've offered for that assertion is your say-so. My counter argument is a lot of senior professionals who say otherwise, though, I will grant you that none of them could tell me why (granted none of them are lawyers).

What they say has nothing to do with permits, unless they are the permit officers.

Point to a project where you think they needed a permit, because you keep insisting it is so. How do you want me to answer if there is nothing in any local rules saying this is true, when you just say yes it is true?

Most of the time states do not maintain a city, the city does. What would the state work on in a city when they have to work on state projects?

A state road etc., does not belong to the city. They city issues permits in the city.

new-south-wales australia
Yes, but …
Planning in NSW is governed by the Environmental Planning and Assessment Act.
Australia has three tiers of government - Federal, State and Local, but Local governments are a creation of state law. The approval of development is assigned to consent authorities which all local governments are but there are also consent authorities that are administrative arms of the state (e.g. the Sydney Harbour Foreshore Authority), or local planning authorities that are subsets or supersets of local government. However, for any given development, there is one, and only one, responsible planning authority.
Not all developments require planning authority permission, but if a state development (i.e. a development by the state) does, then it must be sought.
However, a planning authority may only refuse a state development with the permission of the Minister and may only impose those conditions that the Minister allows.
So, a “higher authority” has to seek permission but it can only be refused if the higher authority agrees.
Federal development must comply with both state and Federal law, so the Federal government seeks approval the same way as anyone else. However, if push came to shove, Federal law trumps state law so if they really, really want to, they can pass a law allowing them to do whatever they want.

Yes, localities can enforce local rules and regulations.
Many times the state level construction projects are done on state owned land, and therefore do not require a permit.

This answer doesn't say anything that my question didn't already. I want to know why the state doesn't need local approval.

@Pyrotechnical you just insist it doesn't. That is not true.

I honestly don't know what you're trying to suggest. Your own answer says that state level projects don't require a local permit; I'm asking you to tell me why that is.

My answer does not say state projects do not need a local permit.

What do you think they need the permit for is the thing? Their roads are theirs.

Not all state-owned properties fall within a public right-of-way. As stated in the question, an historic property could be on a parcel of land owned by a State or County.

So why would you get a city permit for that? @Pyrotechnical

Why would the city issue a permit on state land? @Pyrotechnical

I think the question is about land owned by a higher-level entity (e.g. the state), but physically within the boundaries of a lower-level entity (e.g. a city). Does the lower-level entity have any jurisdiction?

Of course not. How could that be?

The city can only issue a permit for the city.

A state highway is not part of the city.

@Jen the second paragraph of my answer specifically answers that.

Your premise that these things owned by the state are part of the city is not correct.
